# How certificates are really imported in JAVA?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

The following code is the common way of establishing a connection to create an array of certificates by given a URL link (that I use it in my program):

```
URL destinationURL = new URL("https://www.google.com");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL.openConnection();
con.connect();
Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
```

My question is how `con.getServerCertificates()` really imports all the certificates chanining into Java from given a URL link, does `con.getServerCertificates()` always set a SSL connection to the webpage and **import** all the certificates chaining into an array OR does it just use (cacerts file) that comes with JKD ?

Answer (score 0):

It connects to the server and gets the certificates.

There's no way it could have all the certificates already stored in a file, because then Java would have to update every time a certificate was added, removed or replaced anywhere on the Internet. And that obviously doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)
Do you think such a connection is run using SSL ?

Comment: Yes. But I haven't tested it. If you really need to know for some reason, then you could use a program like Wireshark to see what actually gets sent.